# sequelize-typescript array of numbers decleration gives typescript error

Tags: typescript, sequelize-typescript

I am using PostgreSQL, Sequelize, Sequelize-TypeScript and TypeScript for my application. I need a `Role` table in which each `role` has multiple `permissions` (of type integer). I am following the [sequelize-typescript docs](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#model-definition). My declaration is as follows:

```
@Table
export default class Role extends Model {
    @HasMany(() => number)
    declare permissions: Number[]
}
```

For a similar model I use `@HasMany(() => MyType)` and `MyType[]`. That works as expected.

However this piece of code throws the following error: `'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`.

When using `@HasMany(() => Number)` (capital "N") I get another error:

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter<any, unknown>, foreignKey?: string | undefined): Function', gave the following error.
    Type 'NumberConstructor' is not assignable to type 'ModelType<any, unknown>'.
    Type 'Number' is missing the following properties from type 'Model<unknown, any>': $add, $set, $get, $count, and 32 more.
Overload 2 of 2, '(associatedClassGetter: ModelClassGetter<any, unknown>, options?: HasManyOptions | undefined): Function', gave the following error.
    Type 'NumberConstructor' is not assignable to type 'ModelType<any, unknown>'.
```

What am I missing? Am I not supposed to use arrays of primitive types?

PS: changing `declare permissions: Number[]` to `declare permissions: number[]` does not seem to have any impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HasMany refers only to relations to other models, and by your description you need a column to hold an array of numbers, which is not a relation to other models, it is just a regular column.

If you want to save an array of numbers, create a normal column with the [@Column](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript#column-api) decorator and since it's postgres, define it as an array of numbers:

```
@Table
export default class Role extends Model {
    @Column(DataType.ARRAY(DataType.INTEGER)) //this is the actual column type
    permissions: number[] //this is just a typescript type, for usage in the code
}
```

Here are the docs for [DataTypes](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html), which sequelize-typescript re-exports as DataType

Something that you are strugling also, is using types outside of typescript domain, like in the callback of the decorator, [**Number**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is a primitive object that exists in javascript while [**number**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#number) is a basic type that exists in typescript only, and so, it can only be used in types. The two have a correlation, but are different things.

You cannot return a type:

```
const bar = () => number //it will throw a compilation error, as you cannot use a type as a value
```

But you can define it as the return type of the function

```
const bar = (): number => 1
const foo = (): number => Number(4)
```

So inside the callback, you can only use something that exists in javascript, that is why other classes like `@HasMany(() => MyType)` work.